# Column-based-Constraint in SQL to hide or not-retrieve rows

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose we have a table with an `id`, `service_start` date and `service_end` date.

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
   id int PRIMARY KEY,
   service_start date,
   service_end date
) ;
```

Inserting one row..

`INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (1, '2020-01-01', '2020-01-10');`

If we query this table all the rows in it will be retrieved.

Is there a way where we can hide or not-retrieve rows based on a 'column-dependent constraint'. A constraint, which depends on the values of a particular column.

i.e in this case, if the `SYSDATE` (while querying) is in between '2020-01-01' and  '2020-01-10', then this particular row should not be retrieved while querying this table (`select * from table1`). The notion is the vehicle is under service, hence will not be retrieved.

I suppose a Trigger is required? What are the other options?

I need this requirement on a MYSQL database.

Comment: What? Just sounds like you need to do a `SELECT` with a `WHERE` clause

Comment: @JamesS No. User could be just listing the vehicles available. But if it happened to be queried at a time within the service period, even the ```select * from table1``` should not return such rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a VIEW to provide most kinds of filters.

I tested your table this way, with dates so that the current date is between the service start and end date:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (1, '2022-08-10', '2022-08-20');

mysql> select * from table1;
+----+---------------+-------------+
| id | service_start | service_end |
+----+---------------+-------------+
|  1 | 2022-08-10    | 2022-08-20  |
+----+---------------+-------------+

mysql> create view view1 as select * from table1 
  where curdate() not between service_start and service_end;

mysql> select * from view1;
Empty set (0.01 sec)
```

Constraints and triggers affect what you can insert/update/delete, they have no effect on select.